# A Question On Root Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If z is a positive integer, is there any work pertaining to
the number of positive integers whose nth root is approximately z (i.e. after rounding to the nearest whole
number)? Is there a formula for the exact number of these? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Like finding $a,b$ such that $a\le k\le b\Leftrightarrow \left\lfloor \sqrt[n]{k}+\frac12\right\rfloor=z$? This can be done by hand.

Comment: Just look at numbers like $z^n \pm 1$. You can find examples for every $z$ and every $n$.